# BIOS Video Services AH = 6 Scroll Page Up

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

I'm working on a procedure that will display an ASCIIZ string with embedded control characters (1 - 31). One of the features is the ability to write to a page that is not active (*being displayed*), particularly the scrolling functions 6 & 7. To date, I have this and am contemplating writing to video directly when the displayed page is not the one being written to.

```
    Scroll: mov     cx, [cs:di+2]       ; Get top/left of window.
            mov     dx, [cs:di]         ; Get coordinates of bottom/right of window
            bt      word [StsB], SamePg ; Are we writing to active window
            jnc     .DirV               ; Scroll with algo that addresses video memory

    ; As we writing to active page, BIOS function can be used to scroll window up one line.

            mov     ah, RCA             ; Read character & attribute at cursor position
            int     VIDEO
            push    bx                  ; Preserve working page & attribute
            mov     bh, ah              ; BH = page required by INT
            mov     ah, SPU             ; Set function Scroll Page Up
            mov     al, 1               ; for one line
            int     VIDEO
            pop     bx

    .done:  mov     dl, cl              ; Set DL to point to left margin
            clc                         ; Tell caller we want to position cursor
            ret

    ; BIOS function does not allow a page that is not the active page so we need to
    ; address video memory directly.

    .DirV:
            jmp     .done
```

This got me thinking, why don't I just activate page, do the scroll and revert back. First thing that came to mind was, flicker. Although DOSBOX and BOCHs are part of my development environment, I never put too much store into their accurate representation of what real hardware will do.

> Have you ever activated a page, done a scroll, deactivated it on real hardware?

Logic dictates video controler probably does need some settling time, that would cause flicker, but hence the question.

Comment: Back when this stuff was real, one simply didn't use BIOS interrupt at all, because it was too slow for anything serious. Basic console I/O is fine, any text UI like Borland's "Turbo Vision" drawing windows and menus would be hopeless, so only direct VRAM writes were used. And you did reprogram the VGA registers directly as needed, to change displayed page flicker-free, in sync with V-blank period. Using BIOS interrupt would at best save you just few instructions, at worst it was risking to hit some weird BIOS not implementing the stuff you expect... Changing page is probably fast, scroll not.

Comment: So there's like zero point to use BIOS, working with the EGA/VGA directly was simple enough, actually it was pure joy after some of the wicked schemas of display HW in 8 bit computers... The modern dosbox/BOCHS are simulating overpowered machines, with a bit of dosbox tuning you will end with a "386" which is near 500-1000MHz power, while the real thing was 40MHz at most IIRC. Plus memory latencies... the simulated memory is usually at least 5-10 times faster than classic middle-era VGA adapters.

Comment: @MichaelPetch really, so the label in my source `DirV` wasn't any kind of indicator that's where I was headed. What in my question gave you the idea I was having difficulty. I was simply seeking input from those that had practical experience with real hardware which the next two comments after your addressed directly.

Comment: @Shift_Left : The fact you are even contemplating an active page switch to do the scroll tells me that you may not realize how easy it is to do your own. Quite frankly, based on my 30+ years of using the BIOS and using the video card directly I wouldn't even attempt a BIOS based solution for this.

Comment: @Ped7g `Changing page is probably fast` and I had thought about that, but there is a windowing scheme I'm thinking about implementing and not sure for the purposes of scrolling, if that would work for me. This would be a lot less complicated if BIOS implementers would have be a lot more consistent with their ABI.

Comment: @MichaelPetch my motives, intentions and what I realize are irrelevant. I came to this forum to ask a specific question, delineated in yellow. Although I know I'm going to get opinions, they are not unwelcomed so long as there is at least something relevant now or maybe in the future. I've chosen, illogical or not a BIOS oriented paradigm. If at all possible, I would like to stay that course, but the fact is, after some user interaction, protected and long modes will completely render this question moot and the BIOS will be toast.

Comment: @Ped7g haven't delved into emulators that deep yet, but I can see it might be something to consider once I get into protected or long modes. Universally, there seems to be a pretty negative opinion about BIOS and probably not unjustifiable so, but it makes me wonder, how did it survive this long. I suppose not unlike A20, backward compatibility has a lot to do with it.

Comment: BIOS is useful if you have limited resources and are in real mode.

Comment: BIOS implementers were not consistent with anything, they barely managed to implement about 70% of services correctly, even the most basic ones were sometimes bugged, and did need extra detection in app code and workaround. You probably didn't get the "slow" part, you don't need to worry about any flickering with BIOS scroll, it will simply take so long, that the screen image will be well stabilized. IIRC on 286 machines using the BIOS scroll for ~10 lines did take easily over 300ms (while the direct VRAM manipulation was within 5ms done). BIOS did survive so long, because it boots bootloader.

Comment: Since there nobody sane is using it for anything else, so it's OK to stay indefinitely. And it does not, UEFI coming... and guess what, it's another bag of inconsistencies and problems... history repeats itself. ... And about my claim "didn't implement services correctly" .. that's actually quite unfair, because BIOS services were never standardized in proper way, it was IBM PC BIOS vs others stealing from them, extending as they did see it will fit, and the best extensions survived and were copied further. So basically any BIOS did work well, it was your app making wrong assumptions... :D

Comment: @MichaelPetch there, you feel better now that you've down voted my question.

Comment: i haven't down voted your question. Good try. If you want me to downvote I can oblige if you wish.

Comment: @Ped7g I wondered about UEFI as you'd never get the impression that was the case from the authors of the specification. I guess there is no surprise, Linus dumped the BIOS almost right away and characterized it as "stinking".

Comment: Linus called EFI a stinking mess that was **not** better than BIOS (legacy). He characterized EFI as inferior to BIOS(legacy).

Comment: @MichaelPetch was that just a generalization or was he specific. If so, I would be interested to read what he has to say. Do you have link to where he talks about the specification and/or firmware. He does strike me though as having a bit of an agnostic edge to him, so it could be he just has an arbitrary bias.

Comment: That didn't take long. First hit in google is; http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/efi.html

Comment: oh, that includes pretty much third confirmation of our bias, that you should run away from BIOS as fast as possible... :P :D

Answer (score 4):

> Have you ever activated a page, done a scroll, deactivated it on real hardware?

For those that know me it should come as no surprise that I have written code like that a long time ago. It was on a 166MHz Pentium and it produced no flicker at all. This would not have been the case on a 8088 XT.

Next code will scroll the non-displayed page (1) and quickly return to the active page (0). All numbers apply to video mode 3 (80x25):

```
mov     ax, 0501h           ;BIOS.SelectDisplayPage
int     10h

mov     dx, 184Fh           ;BottomRight (79,24)
xor     cx, cx              ;UpperLeft (0,0)
mov     bh, 07h             ;WhiteOnBlack
mov     ax, 0601h           ;BIOS.ScrollWindowUp (1 row)
int     10h

mov     ax, 0500h           ;BIOS.SelectDisplayPage
int     10h
```

If the above code is used in rapid succession (something you normally don't do) then the risk for some flicker becomes real.
Because today's computers are so fast (even the first Pentiums were fast in this respect) a single invocation of the above code works fine.

---

### But it's possible to avoid all risk of flicker and still use BIOS for its scrolling capabilities.

Your question today only exists because the developers of BIOS omitted the DisplayPage parameter on the functions 06h and 07h.
What if you could add it yourself? Beneath code does exactly that:

```
push    ds
xor     ax, ax
mov     ds, ax
push    word [044Eh]        ;Start of current page
push    word [0462h]        ;Index of current page
mov     word [044Eh], 4096
mov     byte [0462h], 1     ;The missing parameter for functions 06h and 07h

mov     dx, 184Fh           ;BottomRight (79,24)
xor     cx, cx              ;UpperLeft (0,0)
mov     bh, 07h             ;WhiteOnBlack
mov     ax, 0601h           ;BIOS.ScrollWindowUp (1 row)
int     10h

pop     word [0462h]
pop     word [044Eh]
pop     ds
```

The BIOS.SelectDisplayPage function 05h updates a couple of BIOS variables and sets the StartAddressLow and StartAddressHigh CRT Controller registers.
If you yourself only change these few BIOS variables, then the graphics hardware will continue to refresh the active page (based on the untouched registers) while BIOS will operate on the non-displayed page. Simple and effective!

Comment: Only recently had I discovered changing values in BDA, and in some cases, it would yield immediate results. I've resolved though to implement a striped down version of what I want in real mode, that doesn't depend on scrolling. I'll still get the level of verbosity I want, but some of it will be in code rather than control features in the ASCII string.